# how to handle multiple paypal buttons on the same form

Tags: paypal

I have three items, and next to each have the paypal "addtocart" button.  each button works if it's the only one on the page ... I believe that's because each button is wrapped in it's own form tags.  How can I get multple buttons on the page?

I have tried single form tag, renaming the cmd buttons and image, but then they just go to the paypal home page.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a regular [Buy Now button](https://www.paypal.com/pdn-item).  You need to make sure you're using an actual [Add to Cart button](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_shoppingcart-intro-outside).  The buttons will still be within their own form tags, but they're a little different to handle the different tasks.  Then you'll also include (optionally) a View Cart button.

Here's another [guide that should be useful](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_paypal_shopping_cart).